# PySerial data update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I try to communicate with FPGA over UART. There is a potentiometer that is connected to ADC pins of the FPGA, I want to send to ADC output to the PC. On the PC side I try to read these incoming data with PySerial. But when I change the ADC input, incoming data that I read on the Python does not change. In another serial monitor program I can see the updated data simultaneously. What do I miss in the Python?

Here this is the code I am working on

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
      port='COM31',
      baudrate=19200,
      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
while True:
    in_bin = ser.read()
    in_hex = hex(int.from_bytes(in_bin,byteorder='little'))
    print(in_hex,end=' ')
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ser.reset_input_buffer()` before `ser.read()` or `ser.readline()`.